# Jenkins Pipeline: Set environment variable based on parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to set an environment variable in a Jenkins pipeline job based on a parameter passed into the job; this way I can use the environment variable in every stage of the pipeline that requires it.  I tried using a switch statement in the environment block:

```
parameters {
    choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: 'dev\nst\nprod', description: 'Environment')
}
environment {
  script {
    switch(env.ENVIRONMENT) {
      case 'dev':
        BRANCH = master
        break
      case 'st':
        BRANCH = 2020Q1
        break 
      case 'prod':
        BRANCH = 2019Q4
        break        
    }
  }
}
```

However this didn't work, the job tried to evaluate all the lines before the equals sign as the KEY name:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 9: "script {
    switch(env.ENVIRONMENT) {
      case 'dev':
        BRANCH" is not a valid identifier and cannot be used for an environment variable. Identifiers must start with a letter or underscore and can contain only letters, numbers or underscores. @ line 9, column 7.
     script {
```

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Your `ENVIRONMENT` value is in the `params` map and not the `env` map at that point.

Comment: @MattSchuchard you're right the statement should be `switch(params.ENVIRONMENT)`

Comment: You may consider using Active Choices plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/ This plugin allows to set build parameters depending on other parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve this. here is a one of them:

```
parameters {
   choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: 'dev\nst\nprod', description: 'Environment')
}

stages(){
  stage("some stage"){
    steps {
        script{
            switch(env.ENVIRONMENT) {
              case 'dev':
                env.BRANCH = "master"
                break
              case 'st':
                env.BRANCH = "2020Q1"
                break 
              case 'prod':
                env.BRANCH = "2019Q4"
                break        
            }
            withEnv(["BRANCH=${env.BRANCH}"]) {
                ...................................
                ...................................
                ...................................

           }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: after the switch statement the BRANCH variable is available in the environment for this and all stages, rendering the `withEnv` section  unnecessary.

Comment: @matus correct since it's setting an env variable that automatically makes it available in all stages, thanks!